# How to write xpath or locator for below td

Tags: css, arrays, string, xpath, css-selectors

[image: UI screen shot]Here, I have to put all the td tags in an array and compare with the database data. Here, I am getting xpath only for one td. Please tell me how to find those elements and put it in array. So that I can take for loop and check the data with database table data. I want those td with list_UID. I am attaching here with the screen shot

```
<table id="list" class="table table-hover table-stripe ui-jqgrid-btable" 
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" tabindex="0" role="grid" 
aria-multiselectable="true" aria-labelledby="gbox_list" style="width: 
2685px;">
<tbody>
<tr class="jqgfirstrow" style="height:auto" role="row">
<tr id="1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" 
role="row">
<td class="ui-state-default jqgrid-rownum" aria-describedby="list_rn" 
title="1" style="text-align:center;width: 40px;" role="gridcell">1</td>
<td aria-describedby="list_cb" style="text-align:center;width: 25px;" 
role="gridcell">
<td aria-describedby="list_Info" title="" style="" role="gridcell">
<td aria-describedby="list_UID" title="201607051541214549899" style="" 
role="gridcell">201607051541214549899</td>
<td aria-describedby="list_NoofActivities" title="" style="" 
role="gridcell">
<td aria-describedby="list_Executor" title="" style="" role="gridcell">
<td aria-describedby="list_Title" title="Mr." style="" 
role="gridcell">Mr.</td>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with correct html and multiple examples? Also, what language are you using on the backend?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all tds which contains `list_UID`, you can simply find it by using `cssSelector` as below (Assuming you are using java) :-

```
List<WebElement> list_UID = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[aria-describedby='list_UID']"));
```

**Edited**:- if you want header with the data list and your header id is different then try using `By.xpath()` with `|` condition as below :-

```
List<WebElement> list_UID = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".//th[@id='list_Village'] | .//td[@aria-describedby='list_UID']"));
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: how to get header as UID for that column?

Comment: @SuneelKuppili you have shared only data rows..If you want header as well need to share header HTML as well..:)

Comment: <th id="list_Village*" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr ui-state-hover" role="columnheader" style="width: 100px;">
<span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" style="cursor: col-resize;"/>
<div id="jqgh_list_Village*" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">
Village*

Comment: @SuneelKuppili Ok then try with `|` and provide both `xpath`,, see updated answer..:)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `.//*[@id='1']/td[4]` returns only one element is because you're explicitly asking for only one element twice. Once, with `[@id='1']`, because `id` attributes are unique, and second with `td[4]`, asking for just the fourth `td` element.

> I want those td with list_UID.

Then you should write your XPath expression to do what you want:

```
.//td[@aria-describedby='list_UID']
```

This gets all `td` elements whose `area-describedby` attribute is `"list_UID"`.

Comment: No, I got the elements in the list. But I have to compare the data from a column in the database with the column in the web table. I am not getting the reference to compare.